# using rsync through secure ssh in a cron job

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync, network-attached-storage

I am trying to set up a shell script under Debian GNU/Linux to backup a directory and subdirectories to a remote NAS running Linux over SSH. This connection has to be encrypted.

I have tried a couple different approaches involving `rsync rsh` and such but without luck. I know how to set up the `crontab`, but I need a script that will run unattended (i.e., it won't ask for password)

Could anyone help me?

EDIT:
I can successfully login without a password now.

The problem now is to get rsync to copy the files in `/backups/` to `[remote system]:/backups/`

It only copies one folder from `/backups/` to `[remote system]:/backups/`.

EDIT: Seems local system has one /backups and one /backup... I have tried with /backups when I should have used /backup...

Final command: `rsync -avzr -e ssh /backup/ admin@[IP]:/backups/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rsync since 2.6.x defaults to using ssh for transfers. So it's already taken care of as long as your remote NAS rsync is supported.

As to password less unattended transfers, setup ssh key based authentication for the user you are running the cron as and that should be done. Here is how you set it up -- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ssh-public-key-based-authentication-how-to.html

Comment: Ok, would you care explaining this step-by-step? I tried something called `keychain` without luck...

Comment: updated my answer :)

Comment: Ok thanks, now logging in works without a password. I'll just google how to use rsync and report back if I can't get it to work!

Comment: how should the rsync command look like? It does copy recursive directories but not files...

Comment: Post your rsync command

Comment: `rsync --recursive --whole-file --compress --checksum --update -v -e ssh /backups/* admin@212.86.7.170:/backups/`

Comment: Any reason why you are skipping checksum and copying entire files instead of deltas?

Comment: No reason. Just experimented with the options and those sounded reasonable...

Comment: Try, `rsync -avz /backups/ admin@212.86.7.170:/backups/`

Comment: Still won't work...

Comment: `[/backups] # ls`
`eResk/`
`[/backups] # cd ..`
`[/] # ls`
`Qmultimedia@ dev/         lib/         mnt/         proc/        share/       tmp/
backups/     etc/         linuxrc@     opt/         root/        stunnel.pid  usr@
bin/         home@        lost+found/  php.ini@     sbin/        sys/         var/`
`[/] # cd backups/`
`[/backups] # ls`
`eResk/`

Comment: [root@eresk eResk]# rsync -avz /backups/ admin@212.86.7.170:/backups/
sending incremental file list
./
eResk/

sent 50 bytes  received 19 bytes  46.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

Comment: Are you sure `admin@212.86.7.170:/backups/` exists?

Comment: Update: It seems to copy folders only one deep. It won't copy the folder 'test' which is in /backup/eResk/

Comment: The -a flag to rsync also has the recursive option and it will copy it recursively unless there are permission issues. Also, you have to ensure you are running the command from the parent directory of the directory you want rsync'd

Comment: oh yes it does. contents of it is one folder, which when removed and rsync command re-ran gets created (eResk)

Comment: could there be something wrong on the server-side? Because I have done everything that you have said but nothing seems to help... :/

Comment: could the same results be achieved using something like SFTP?

Comment: This is not a problem with ssh. sftp here won't help in backups. Are you saying subfolders are not rsync'd? or if you delete a file in the local directory, it is not deleted in the destination when you re-run rsync?

Comment: So, the files on the local system are located in /backups. /backups has 1 folder and 1 file. The file is test.txt and the folder is eResk. eResk contains a folder named success and a file named test.txt. Now when i run rsync, all that happens is that into the remote systems /backups/ a new directory called eResk is created. It is completely empty. Very strange behaviour if you ask me.

Comment: Can you delete the contents of remote /backups directory and re-run the following command? `rsync -avvz -i backups/ admin@212.86.7.170:/backups` Paste the complete rsync output

Comment: ***I think it's time to edit both the question and answer to contain some of the info in this comment thread*** -- You guys are tripping automatic alarms for too many comments.  If the issue is really that complex it may not be a good fit for a Q&A site...

Comment: Ouch :) It's not really that complex. It's ideal this is moved to a chat or even better the OP improves the question with ALL the details. Moderators, it's your call.

Comment: Thank you very much @Chida! it seems I messed up some details myself which screwed up the whole thing. Now everything works as expected! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can also pass this flag to rsync to use a file for the password:

--password-file

Can easily chmod the file to 400 so no one but your user can read that file (and root of course)

Answer (score 2):

Ssh Key syncing you said you had this working but i thought i would still post the steps

ssh in to your NAS

To make the Key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa on local machine
```

Then sync to the computer you will be backing up from

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname    ‘cat>>.ssh/authorized_keys’
```

Rync Backup script -This will make a backup folder for today ,then sycn yesterdays files todays this will reduce the load on the network, then it will rsync todays to be backed up.

```
#!/bin/sh

mkdir -p /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$host/$username

rsync -avz /storage/backups/`date --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date--date=yesterday    +\%A`/$host/$username/ /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$host/$username/

rsync -avz -e ssh  /home/username/ /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/$host/$username/
```

You will also need a script which will clean up the backups: this will keep a week backup ,I can confirm that this works on Netgear's ready nas

```
#!/bin/sh

# Definitions
sevendaysago=$(date --date='6 days ago' +%Y-%m-%d-%A)

# Delete backups from 7 days ago
rm -rf /storage/backups/$sevendaysago
```

you will need to run this to make scripts runable

```
chmod u+x script.sh
```

in cron you will just need to add via crontab -e

```
@daily sh backupscript
1 17 * * * sh dailycleanup
```

Comment: To a more detailed version of the script http://timothydavidellis.com/blog/?p=36

Comment: use find + rm, use `rsync -azP` instead. in cron you don't need `-v`...