# Using rsync to make daily backups every 24hrs

Tags: linux, mysql, backup, rsync, database-backup

I would like to backup /home/* /root/* and mysql databases to a set of RAIDed drives.

Performance wise I want to do incremental backups.

Would this be the idea?

```
rsync -al /home /dev/sdb/backups/home
```

Tricky part. You would have to do a rotate and mysql dump per DB right?

Comment: Look into http://www.rsnapshot.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this will make a nightly backup of home and a back dump of all your mysql data , it will copy the file in to a file named todays date. just mount the new disk and then name it some and adjust the script below , if you have a look at my [blog](http://blog.timothydavidellis.com/?p=36) i have the clean script and also one to email you if it hasn't worked.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 # Server Backup
 mkdir -p /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/server/users
 rsync -avz /storage/backups/`date --date=yesterday +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date --date=yesterday +\%A`/server15/users/ /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/server/users/
 rsync -avz --delete rsync -avz /home/ /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/server/users/
 # Dump Mysql Data
 for database in $(mysql -u root -p(password) -e "show databases" | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v Database| grep -v information_schema | grep -v mysql | grep -v phpmyadmin)
 do
    mysqldump -u root -p(password) $database > /storage/backups/`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`-`date +\%A`/server/$database.sql
 done
```

Comment: also have a look at my answer for this question http://serverfault.com/questions/420923/using-rsync-through-secure-ssh-in-a-cron-job/421862#421862